# why does a scriptblock passed as an argument in invoke-commands argumentlist fail?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

```
function test-scriptblock {
1..10 }
function caller ([scriptblock]$runthis) {
& $runthis
}
```

### the following works fine.

```
caller -runthis ${function:test-scriptblock}
```

### this doesn't work

```
invoke-command -ComputerName localhost -ScriptBlock ${function:caller} -ArgumentList ${function:test-scriptblock}

Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'runthis'. Cannot convert the "
1..10 " value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [], ParameterBindin...mationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I verified that this a "known issue". While in most cases in remoting scriptblocks regurgitate just fine as scriptblocks but with `ArgumentList` they don't, so instead I do

```
function Caller($runthis)
{
   $runthis = [Scriptblock]::Create($runthis)
   &$runthis
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `-ArgumentList` takes in `Object[]`, I think it is received by `caller` as a string. One workaround is this:

```
function caller ($runthis) {
$runthis = $executioncontext.InvokeCommand.NewScriptBlock($runthis)
& $runthis
}
```

Note that something like this works:

```
function caller ($runthis) {
$runthis  | kill
}

$p= Get-Process -name notepad
invoke-command -computer localhost -ScriptBlock ${function:caller} -ArgumentList $p
```

I think scriptblocks are treated differently since it might be considered a security issue to just run them.

Answer (score 0):

Adapted to your initial code, I do it so :

```
caller -runthis (get-item Function:\test-scriptblock).scriptblock
```

A `function` **is not** a `scriptblock`, a `scriptblock` *is* a property of a function.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question. The real problem is in passing it in `ArgumentList`

Comment: I say that because even with `scriptblock` prop it doesn't work from ArgumentList.